# How to forward a Symfony Request to another server using the Http Client (with optional changes)?

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, symfony-http-foundation, symfony-http-client

How to intercept a request and send it with `HttpClient` to another server and return the response from that server after some modification?

The original request will contain data and files. I am looking for the least verbose solution, up to copying the original raw body as a string. The part I am stuck with is plugging the `Request` object to the `HttpClient` request **in the shortest way (without writing code to copy data and headers bit by bit)**, the rest (handling the response) I will manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony's Http Client does not accept an `HttpFoundation\Request` as a parameter to make new requests.

You'll need to convert the `Request` object into the necessary parameters (including converting the path, method, passing appropriate headers, etc) "manually".

Then, you'd have to create the an `HttpFoundation\Response` based on the client's response (which, again, cannot simply be sent back in your controller).

Depending on your specific requirements, it's not particularly onerous. A naive, probably buggy implementation would be something like:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class FooProxy
{
    public function __construct(private HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
    }

    public function __invoke(HttpFoundation\Request $request): HttpFoundation\Response
    {
        $options            = [];
        $newServer          = 'https://www.example.com';
        $options['headers'] = $request->headers->all();
        $options['body']    = $request->getContent();

        $clientResponse = $this->client->request(
            $request->getMethod(),
            $newServer . $request->getRequestUri(),
            $options
        );

        return new HttpFoundation\Response(
            $clientResponse->getContent(false),
            $clientResponse->getStatusCode(),
            $clientResponse->getHeaders(false)
        );

    }
}
```

Again, this is very naive implementation. You'd need to make sure that you deal with any exceptions and edge cases.

Take into account that PHP is not a great choice of language to build a real HTTP proxy.

Comment: Thanks. It's what I did (although 1. files won't be copied in `getContent`, 2. the request will only form correctly if I construct it with `Mime\FormDataPart` and export body as string). For that reason I think it is silly that the `HttpFoundation\Request` cannot be plugged directly into `HttpClient`. Why not use the same interface, when it even has special methods to clone and modify the original request? I don't understand it and I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I did use the answer from @yivi.
But After a while I encounter the error mentioned by @Jacek Krysztofik.

After digging a while, I finnaly find the solution in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/components/http_client.html#uploading-data).

Here is the corrected code:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\Multipart\FormDataPart;

class FooProxy
{
    public function __construct(private HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
    }

    public function __invoke(HttpFoundation\Request $request): HttpFoundation\Response
    {
        $options            = [];
        $newServer          = 'https://www.example.com';
        $options['headers'] = $request->headers->all();
        $options['body']    = $request->getContent();

        if ($request->request->count()) {
            // This is a post request, update the body and headers accordingly
            $formData = new FormDataPart($request->request->all());
            $options['headers'] = array_merge($options['headers'], $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray());
            $options['body'] = $formData->bodyToIterable();
        }

        $clientResponse = $this->client->request(
            $request->getMethod(),
            $newServer . $request->getRequestUri(),
            $options
        );

        return new HttpFoundation\Response(
            $clientResponse->getContent(false),
            $clientResponse->getStatusCode(),
            $clientResponse->getHeaders(false)
        );

    }
}
```

It's proabbly still not 100% bulletproof, but in my case it do the job for get and post requests.